# How to send invitation to google calender from gmail in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, smtp, gmail, smtpclient

I have already written a code in C# to send a mail to the user from my gmail and also sending a attachment if it contains. Now I need to send the invitation so that it marks on customer google calendar.My code for sending a gmail and attachment is :

```
public static void SendEmail(MessageModel message)
        {
            string from = "noreply@test.com";

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(from)) {
                throw new System.Exception("Invalid email configuration ! Missing SupportEmailAddress in Web.config.");
            }
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(from,
                                message.Destination,
                                message.Subject,
                                message.Body)
            {
                IsBodyHtml = true
            };


            if (message.Attachment != null)
            { 
                Attachment attachment = new Attachment(message.Attachment, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
                mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            }

            client.Send(mailMessage);
        }
```

The above code works fine for sending a message and attachment to the user. Now I need to send invitation to them in so that it marks on their google calender. How can I do this?

Comment: Wheres your google calendar API code? have you added them as attendees?

Comment: @DaImTo I literally don't have ideas to integrate with google calender. Do I need to do something else instead of this code?

Comment: Yes, you need to use Google's Calendar [API](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/api/what-are-application-programming-interfaces) to create events in your calendar and invite people. Familiarize yourself with the [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/overview), go through some quickstarts.

Comment: "I literally don't have ideas to integrate with google calender"...then read the documentation for it. https://developers.google.com/calendar/overview . We can't help you if you haven't even done any basic research (because you won't understand what we're telling you).

Answer (score 1):

The thing is i think you may be going about this in the wrong way.  You should consider looking into the Google Calendar API. By doing a [Event.insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) directly into your calendar there by creating a new event. You can then do a [event.update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update) and update the event adding more attendees to the event as you so choose and they will automatically (if you choose to) be notified of invites by google.

The issue here being controlling the event itself.  I would recommend looking into using a service account. You can grant the service account access to your calendar and it will be able to insert and update these events.   The only drawback to this solution will be the emails sent to users notifying them of the event invite.

1. invite will come from the service accounts email address which is ugly.
2. service account invites sending notification emails seams to be buggy lately.

Second option would be to do something like an installed application where by you use Oauth2 authenticate your application once and store the refresh token the application will then pretend to be you and write to the event when ever it needs to.

1. refresh tokens can expire very very rarely but you still should check for this error.
2. invites are sent from you so you will be giving everyone your email address.

A bit of sample code for you. [Google .net samples](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Calendar%20API/v3)